# How In pentaho report designer I want to check if multivalue parameter is empty or null?

Tags: java, pentaho

My parameter definition:

```
        <list-parameter name="Direction" allow-multi-selection="true" strict-values="true" mandatory="false" type="[Ljava.lang.String;" query="DirectionQuery" key-column="BC_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_DIRECTION_NAME" value-column="BC_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_DIRECTION_NAME">
        <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="role">user</attribute>
        <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="parameter-render-type">list</attribute>
        <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="label">Direction</attribute>
        <attribute namespace="http://reporting.pentaho.org/namespaces/engine/parameter-attributes/core" name="hidden">false</attribute>
```

Constraints part in my MQL query

```
<constraint>
  <operator>AND</operator>
  <condition>OR( ISNA([param:Destination Type]);EQUALS([BC_FCT_CALLS.BC_NUMBER_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_CLASSIFICATION];[param:Destination Type]))</condition>
</constraint>
<constraint>
  <operator>AND</operator>
  <condition>OR(COUNTA([param:Direction]) == 0 ;EQUALS([BC_FCT_CALLS.BC_CALL_CLASSIFICATION_DIM_DIRECTION_NAME];[param:Direction]))</condition>
</constraint>
```

First constraint works because the parameter is single value but the second constraint gives me a message CONTA is not supported and ISNA doesn't work if user selects multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to do this, for each multivalue parameter "param1" create another hidden boolean parameter "param1_hidden" in the "post-processor-formula" for the new param use the following formula

```
 =(COUNTA([param1]) = 0 )
```

now in your query

```
OR( EQUALS(TRUE();[param:param1_hidden);EQUALS([TABLE.COLUMN];[param:param1,]))
```